# Generate burndown chart for a swimlane

Tags: jira, burndowncharts

I have added 2 `swimlanes` to manage 2 projects. However, when I generate the `Burndown` chart it displays the performance of both projects. How can I display a `burndown` chart for a particular `swimlane` ?

Note: I am not allowed to add any pluging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Burndown Chart report on Jira's sprint board tracks the progress of all issues in sprint. To view two separate reports you have to create two separate scopes (one per project) and add them to two different sprints. You can run parallel sprints in Jira, just make sure that the Parallel Sprints checkbox is checked in Jira configuration.